For angular webpack based builders, how to config the `define` for tree shaking or compress in the built-in javaScriptOptimizerPlugin
For angular webpack based builders, how to config the define for tree sharking or compress in the built-in  javaScriptOptimizerPlugin ?
async function optimizeWithEsbuild(content, name, options) {
    if (!esbuild) {
        esbuild = new esbuild_executor_1.EsbuildExecutor(options.alwaysUseWasm);
    }
    try {
        return await esbuild.transform(content, {
            minifyIdentifiers: !options.keepIdentifierNames,
            minifySyntax: true,
            // NOTE: Disabling whitespace ensures unused pure annotations are kept
            minifyWhitespace: false,
            pure: ['forwardRef'],
            legalComments: options.removeLicenses ? 'none' : 'inline',
            sourcefile: name,
            sourcemap: options.sourcemap && 'external',
            define: options.define,
            target: options.target,
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        if (isEsBuildFailure(error)) {
            return error;
        }
        throw error;
    }
}

I want to know the entry point to config the defined property and so on. And does angular allow us to config the tree sharking here？
